# CNC USB keep randomly disconnect while plug Computor notebook to wall plug

Tags: ac, usb-device

My CNC Machine used Mach3 USB board, Switching PSU (for stepper) and inverter fpr spindle.
When notebook run from battery, every work fine until battery run out.
After thatr, I plug computor notebook adaptor then USB keep connected and disconnected continueusly.
My question what cause these problem (USB connection unreliable when using ac plug for both device and PC) and how to prevent that?
Note Mach3 USB Board powered by USB. Also my PC run win10 (maybe that can cause problem)

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're not asking an electronics design question.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. matbe there are some factor that well know in electronic design which cause that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EMI Solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3PlfR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a common problem with multiple PSU's, one being a floating supply (Stepper) and the other a mobile with a charger connected or a tower that is earth grounded.
There is a lot of Common Mode (CM) Noise from the Stepper load and this interference with USB when search ground noise is conducted over the data.

I expect the proper fix to have a lower impedance earth connection to the Stepper PSU to shunt the CM noise that it does not pass thru the USB. If this only marginally improves it, A common earth noise ground needs to be strapped at both ends or a large CM clam-shell choke added to the cable.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely there is a loop antenna being created when you plug in the notebook and this is picking up noise from the CNC (probably the motor drivers, but it might even be the power adaptor itself) and transferring it to the USB data lines.

Unfortunately the USB data lines use single ended signally for requesting a device reset, and so all the nice twisted pair USB cabling and differential interface is defeated by large amount of interference coupling into the lines and triggering a hardware reset.

This is a well known 'flaw' in the design of USB.

Comment: Anything I can do for these??